# Is there any way to send a data to particular partition of topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

How to send data in kstream to specific topic partition ?

For say topicA partition2

I tried `mysteam.to("topic");`
But it didn't worked

Comment: Please provide more info and code for better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your own partitioner into `KStream.to()` with `Produced`.

See https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#to-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced-

https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Produced.html

Examples for implementations of the `Partitioner` interface can be found here:

- [`DefaultPartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java)
- [`RoundRobinPartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/RoundRobinPartitioner.java)
- [`UniformStickyPartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/UniformStickyPartitioner.java)

Comment: Updated the answer with links to implementations of the `Partitioner` interface.